# Regarding restoration of data via Deja Dup

Tags: data-recovery, restore, deja-dup, data-loss

I recently had a crash while upgrading to 15.04 and lost all my data. I had to reinstall ubuntu from scratch to resolve this. However, I used to back up data regularly via deja dup. Is it possible to restore my lost data somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you backed up your data to an external drive or cloud service. You need the files stored in the `deja-dup` folder to restore. I recommend installing Dropbox and changing your backup folder location to be inside your Dropbox folder so you can restore.

Comment: what do you mean with "deja-dup" folder? Could you specify the exact path of the folder you put in your Dropbox? Did you also put your .ssh and .gnupg folder in the Dropbox. Seems like Deja Dup needs those folders to restore encrypted backups, but it also feels like adding another security leack to do so