# Deja Dup risk of data loss

Tags: ssh, backup, encryption, gnupg, deja-dup

I'm currently using Deja Dup ("Ubuntu Backups") to create backups of my data. However when reading around I see a lot of issues of people being unable to restore their backups in case the catastrophe hits.

- [one person reports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154882/layers-of-confusion-about-deja-dup-encrypted-backups) he might have deleted his ".ssh" or ".gnupg" folder which probably contained the necessary for decrypting the backups

Obviously I want to be able to reinstall my backups whenever needed, meaning:

- my computer gets hacked and .ssh and .gnupg are deleted
- I mistakenly delete .ssh or .gnupg (might even be due to a necessary reinstallation of the operating system)

Question:
How do I prevent data loss, when the above described "catastrophe" hits?
Can I note the encryption password on a piece of paper, if yes, which one?

- some .ssh key?
- some more keys? (gnupg?)

Some more infos I found around the topic "issues with restoring encrypted backups in Deja Dup":

- [place Deja Dup keys / installation files in Dropbox to prevent data loss](https://askubuntu.com/a/631938/380330)
- this guy is unable to restore the backup [because of a Deja Dup software bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134577/deja-dup-invalid-data-sha1-hash-mismatch-for-file?rq=1)

Comment: and so to your question?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a few parts to unpack …

**Re: Digital keys**

One of the things that I do for SSH and other keys is keep them in a LUKS encrypted volume on a USB stick. The USB stick is attached to my keychain, and always with me. If my house were to burn down, or all of my computers confiscated by a government organization, or my son were to go on a venomous rampage, I could use the keys on the USB stick with one of my offsite backups to restore 100% of my irreplaceable data in a matter of hours.

**Re: Backup Restoration Failure**

All backup process that is never tested can offer you is a false sense of security. Test your backups by restoring them to a virtual machine at regular intervals. I have mostly automated this process away, so test a full déjà dup restoration on a VirtualBox instance thrice a week. Errors result in notifications. Notifications result in a manual verification of the failure followed by a fix.

Most *normal* people would sleep just fine doing it once every few months.

Comment: very insightful answer. However do you know specifically about the necessity of the keeping a separate backup of the .ssh and .gnupg folders in order to restore encrypted deja dup backups?